# Getting user by instagram photos (tag)

Tags: instagram

Oh, hello.

I'm doing an experiment with instagram api For now, i can show the photos by instagram tags. But i have one question:

- Theres a way to show the instagram photo + the user name(the person who post the photo)?

Thanks ;)

Answer (score 1):

If I understood your question correctly, assuming you have the URL of an Instagram image like http://instagram.com/p/p2P-98uHBp/ then you could use Instagam's [Embedding Endpoints](http://instagram.com/developer/embedding/#) to get `json` information from that link.

This URL format will return the json data you need  :

http://api.instagram.com/oembed?url=http://instagram.com/p/p2P-98uHBp/

The user name can be extracted from an ajax response like :

```
var instaURL = "http://api.instagram.com/oembed?url=http://instagram.com/p/p2P-98uHBp/";
$(document).ready(function () {
    $.ajax({
        url: instaURL,
        dataType : "jsonp", // this is important
        cache: false,
        success: function (response) {
            alert("the instagram user is = " + response.author_name);
        },
        error: function () {
            alert("couldn't process the instagram url");
        }
    });
});
```

See **[JSFIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/fEQa6/1/)**